# How to Create ID Variable based on Rolling Date Rule?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, lapply, zoo

This is embarrassing: I admit several pieces of code of mine have a similar structure to this:

[image]

Arghhhh! Do real programmers cringe when they see something like this?

The figure should be self-explanatory: 
I need a variable called **Season** that returns an ID "(year-1)_(year)" based on the WEATHERDATE column.

So, any row with dates from '1998-06-15' to '1999-06-14' should return "1998-1999" under the **Season** ID Column.

The WEATHERDATE column simply runs from 1998-01-01 to TODAY.

I bet there's a one/two liner solution to this. I've tried the *zoo package* but no success.

Any R wizard to point me to the obvious solution I'm missing here?

***REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:

```
WEATHERDATE <- seq(as.Date("1998-01-01"), len=99999, by=1)
VARIABLE    <- rnorm(n = length(WEATHERDATE))
data_mex    <- data.frame(WEATHERDATE, VARIABLE)
## how to create SEASON based on dates??
# I would then run the code block from above, something like:
data_mex <- within(data_mex, Season[DATEWEATHER >= ymd(StartOfSeason)+365*0   & DATEWEATHER < ymd(StartOfSeason)+365*1 ] <- "1998-1999")
```

Of course a solution where I don't have to come back and touch the code every year would be ideal :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cut.Date` and `seq.Date` to do this in two lines in base R:

```
seasons <- format(as.Date(cut.Date(as.Date(data_mex$WEATHERDATE),
               breaks=seq.Date(as.Date("1997-06-15"),
                 as.Date("2280-06-15", "year"))), "%Y")
data_mex$seasons <- paste0(seasons, "-", as.numeric(seasons) + 1)
```

Note I have used `"2280-06-15"` as the latest date for your seasons, but you may want to replace that with `Sys.Date()`, or whenever is appropriate for your task.

This returns:

```
> head(data_mex)
  WEATHERDATE   VARIABLE   seasons
1  1998-01-01 -0.2260734 1997-1998
2  1998-01-02  0.3222805 1997-1998
3  1998-01-03 -0.1554167 1997-1998
4  1998-01-04 -0.5591154 1997-1998
5  1998-01-05  1.0729737 1997-1998
6  1998-01-06  1.0030025 1997-1998

> tail(data_mex)
      WEATHERDATE   VARIABLE   seasons
99994  2271-10-10 0.59986466 2271-2272
99995  2271-10-11 0.37304603 2271-2272
99996  2271-10-12 1.30822156 2271-2272
99997  2271-10-13 0.01204986 2271-2272
99998  2271-10-14 0.87340544 2271-2272
99999  2271-10-15 0.44098083 2271-2272
```

Comment: Very nice, @ajrwhite. tail(data_mex) shows that it fails for the last year(s) of the dataseries. Any chance you can fix that on your answer?

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to specify the right range in `seq.Date` to suit your data. In this case, I have changed `Sys.Date()` to `"2280-06-15"`, which will give you full coverage of your example dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution you can use to get the desired output:

```
data_mex$seasonId <-
  with(data_mex,
       ifelse(as.numeric(format(WEATHERDATE, '%m')) >= 6 &
                as.numeric(format(WEATHERDATE, '%d')) >= 15,
              paste(format(WEATHERDATE, '%Y'),
                    as.numeric(format(WEATHERDATE, '%Y')) + 1, sep = '-'),
              paste(as.numeric(format(WEATHERDATE, '%Y')) - 1,
                    format(WEATHERDATE, '%Y'), sep = '-')))
```

Resulting output is:

```
head(data_mex)
  WEATHERDATE    VARIABLE  seasonId
1  1998-01-01 -0.02541724 1997-1998
2  1998-01-02 -0.48725913 1997-1998
3  1998-01-03  0.06204881 1997-1998
4  1998-01-04 -0.15207281 1997-1998
5  1998-01-05 -0.61809248 1997-1998
6  1998-01-06 -1.20427734 1997-1998

tail(data_mex)
      WEATHERDATE   VARIABLE  seasonId
99994  2271-10-10 -0.8976144 2271-2272
99995  2271-10-11 -0.5684972 2271-2272
99996  2271-10-12 -0.8847031 2271-2272
99997  2271-10-13 -0.2659979 2271-2272
99998  2271-10-14 -0.9108352 2271-2272
99999  2271-10-15  1.1601581 2271-2272
```

You extract the year portion each time, and paste the lagging or leading year based on the month and day value. `format` method is allowing you extract specific portions of the date.

Comment: thanks, I ended up choosing ajrwhite 's  solution because it's shorter and I can use StartOfSeason variable instead of breaking it up in pieces for MONTH and YEAR (6 and 15 in your solution)